# Split a list of N into 24(for hours) based on the long "curTime" class field it contains

Tags: java, android, algorithm, arraylist

I have an arrayList of size N that contains a class with time stored in it based on System millis. I want to go through the whole arrayList and split it up into one hour chunks. It can only be the last 24 hours starting from now and going back 24 hours. There may be items that fall out of the last 24 hour window though.

I can't believe I'm asking an algorithm question on SO. Thanks for the help.

The large arrayList is made up of basically this item:

```
public class Item {
  private long date;
  private long otherData;
}
```

I'm saving the date in the Item using:

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

Again, I would like to split up the arrayList of Items into 24 separate arrayLists of Items based on their "save date" that used currentTimeMillis() at the time they were saved.

It would be even cooler if the first/newest/most recent bucket ended exactly on the next hour mark then every hour after that. In other words, if I do a request at 7:25PM...it would awesome if the first Item "bucket" only contained entries that were saved in the last 25 minutes. Then, the next 23 "bucket of Items" were broken down on the hour(6:00PM, 5:00PM...).

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would convert the current system time to a `Date` or `Calendar` object.  Using that I can get the minutes of the current hour.  I can then go back to the start of the hour, and iterate on down through each hour.  You can go between `Date` and `milliseconds` easily using `myDate.getTime()` and `new Date(milliseconds)`

Figure out how many milliseconds you need for each section and subtract.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could break up the blocks is by converting the times into a Calendar and checking the [`HOUR_OF_DAY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY). Create a HashMap of hours corresponding with an arrayList of the bucket items then simply loop through and place them in the corresponding list.